# How do I set point density node for smoke?

Tags: animation, texturing, materials, smoke-simulation, point-clouds

I’m trying to make this animation , I’m using particles from an emitter to create the smoke and force fields to give them the direction I want .

The problem is I’d like to shade the smoke as it was very much heated in the center , where the particles flows is , so it looks pretty much like a lighting bolt .

I knew of a function named voxel data in the textures that would allow to achieve this result , but I can’t find it in the new version of blender . Does anyone know what I should do , once I got the smoke from the particles emitter ?

[image: there you can see kind of a bolt at the center of the smoke]

Answer (score 0):

*Q: I knew of a function named voxel data in the textures that would allow to achieve this result , but I can’t find it in the new version of blender . Does anyone know what I should do , once I got the smoke from the particles emitter ?*

---

**Texture > Voxel Data** is feature until Blender 2.79

Since Blender 2.83 you can use a new type of object **Volume**

[image]

For more see [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/volumes/introduction.html) (plus [properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/volumes/properties.html#grids)