# How can I do this on new blender?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I’m trying to make this animation, using particles from an emitter.

The problem is I’d like to shade the smoke as it was very much heated in the centre, where the particles flow is, so it looks pretty much like a lightning bolt.

I knew of a function named voxel data in the textures that would allow achieving this result, but I can’t find it in the new version of blender. Does anyone know what I should do, once I got the smoke from the particles emitter?

[image: there you can see kind of a bolt at the centre of the smoke]

Comment: Please dont ask Questions multiple times. If your Question dosnt recive atention try to clarify it and make it more concise. Maybe read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set point density node for smoke?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174134/how-do-i-set-point-density-node-for-smoke)